# What is the name of this brown fly?

Tags: species-identification

They started mating each other and there are lots of them in our hous. I saw them attached together from their bottom.

[image][image]

---

They have 6 legs and 2 antennae. They have brown wings. i live in iran, tehran. they are about size of fingertip (or smaller)

Comment: Welcomo to Biology SE. I know you are veteran from S overflow, but you should take a look how you should ask at first place. You know, ID questions can be really well  accept but you have to add some information, which somebody can start with. Like, where did you see those bugs, parametr of it and you might get answer. Anyway good luck and enjoy your time on Biology SE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw them in my house. I think they have 6 legs. I dont really know anything about flies. I was just wondering what species are these. Also they fly like a butterfly.

Comment: They have solid brown wings

Comment: Please edit the question to include the details in your comments. You should also note your location as different countries have different species.

Comment: @Michael_A Ive tried to provide information as much as i could.

Comment: They look more like moths than flies.